# Ubuntu 19.04 background kind of pixelized

Tags: nvidia, hibernate, nvidia-optimus, bumblebee, 19.04

I have a problem with my Ubuntu background. It seems to get some kind of pixelized. I searched the internet but couldn't find any solution. My background is the default background from Ubuntu 19.04.

[image: my desktop]

The problem usually occurs after I put my notebook in hibernation mode. I recently installed bumblebee with nvidia drivers. Bumblebee is from the official repos and the drivers from the nvidia ppa.

I'm looking forward to your answers. Thank you!

Comment: I have this also. it's a different kind of pixelation but it doesn'y bother me, because it goes away as soon as you maximize & minimize something or change the background image. you don't have this issue with the nouveau driver so it's a nividia bug as far as I can tell.

Comment: @tatsu max and minimizing doesn't work for me. Changing the background image doesn't work either. Yes, the problem occurs since the nvidia drivers are installed but they aren't even activated if I am on the desktop. Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: No. and I would beinterested in a permanent fix as well. Does it happen for you with every hibernation? because that isn't the case for me. I get it at irregular intervals at wakup. what happens if you have an app fullscreen before you make the computer sleep?

Comment: @tatsu yes it happens every hibernation. I just tried it out and it happened again but with a different hibernation. Now it is kind of black with white pixels and somehow I can recognize a red structure.

Comment: ok so maybe our two symptoms are not related. I only have it once in a while.

Comment: See - https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mutter/+bug/1809407/comments/35
And - https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/mutter/merge_requests/600

Answer (score 0):

I want to suggest a script that "worked" for me. Please, see answer at here: [Flicker after suspend on two monitors](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1157823/flicker-after-suspend-on-two-monitors/1157892#1157892)

I hope you've success...

Comment: I'm not sure if that script would work in this case also since flickering and pixelised screen are two different things.

Comment: Oh, sorry dude, my english is poor. But in my case the problem was pixelized (I need to research to understand :D )