# Desktop wallpaper with artifacts after blocking the screen, ubuntu 19.04

Tags: suspend, ubuntu-gnome, desktop-background, 19.04

When I lock the screen (super + L) or suspend, when unlocking then artifacts appear on the desktop. It does not affect anything else, only the desktop wallpaper. Is it possible to solve it? Thank you.

Screenshot:

[image: Wallpaper with artifacts after scren locking or suspend]

Comment: possible duplicate of : https://askubuntu.com/questions/1143404/ubuntu-19-04-background-kind-of-pixelized

Comment: the motif is different with every machine. probably because of the cpu. mine is  something between what you two have.

Comment: I want to suggest a script that "worked" for me. Please, see my answer here: [Flicker after suspend on two monitors
](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1157823/flicker-after-suspend-on-two-monitors/1157892#1157892) I hope this helps...