# Flicker after suspend on two monitors

Tags: drivers, nvidia, multiple-monitors, suspend, 19.04

I'm relative new at Ubuntu than sorry for any basics erros/confusions...
Recently I've experienced some crahes using two monitor in my laptop. I've noted its almost ever happen when it wake up after suspend (hold down ALT key).
Look at the images bellow

[Flicker at two monitors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ylzLR.jpg)
[Flicker at built-in monitor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RPMW6.jpg)
[Flciker at HDMI monitor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ybrFy.jpg)

I tried login TTY using ALT + CTRL + 3 and command sudo service lightdm restart, but it don't work for me.
In addition, a restart solve the problem, but sometimes I've unsaved work openning and it's not a good idea.
If anyone have a suggestion I appreciate...

Laptop: XPS L502x
VGA: Integrated Intel and Nvidia M525
Driver used: nvidia-390 (instaled by default)
1 build-in monitor (at laptop)
1 HDMI monitor
Ubuntu: 19.04

Comment: Possible duplicate of : https://askubuntu.com/questions/1143404/ubuntu-19-04-background-kind-of-pixelized & https://askubuntu.com/questions/1145386/desktop-wallpaper-with-artifacts-after-blocking-the-screen-ubuntu-19-04

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug#1809407 related here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mutter/+bug/1809407

and a patch to fix while here: https://gist.github.com/satmandu/2f2da70a7a6bbbacdba01ef8fb8c18f4

Please note that the patch needs `systemd-container` and to be in a specific folder to work properly (read carefully the instructions in the links)