# GUI issue in Ubuntu 18 in some applications

Tags: 18.04, graphics, gui

This issue appears when I lock the system and screen turn off. On unlocking, some of the applications have some gui issue like shown in image below.

snapshot here (check right section in image)
[image: snapshot here (check right section in image)]

The issue sometimes resolves on cursor actions like click or hover, but not always.

Applications like VS Code, Google Chrome and some others have this issue. My system has Nvidia graphics card, and I also tried reinstalling its drivers.

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1143404/ubuntu-19-04-background-kind-of-pixelized

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't start ubuntu-desktop after upgrade to 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1031948/cant-start-ubuntu-desktop-after-upgrade-to-18-04)

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! It's unclear (at least to me) exactly what you are asking here. Please [edit] the output of `sudo lshw -C display` into your question. Thank you for helping us help you! If you've tried several versions when installing the nvidia driver you may have inadvertently created a mess. If so you might find [this answer useful.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/481414/install-nvidia-driver-instead-of-nouveau/481540#481540)